# Weird python time.strftime() timezone display

Tags: python, timezone, strftime

It is around "2013-02-27 11:02" (GMT) and, as I am in France my local time is around "2013-02-27 12:02 +0100".
I played the following commands on my machine:

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Apr 14 2012, 04:15:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
>>> paris_time = (time.gmtime(), time.localtime())
>>> paris_time[0]
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=11, tm_min=2, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=58, tm_isdst=0)
>>> paris_time[1]
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=12, tm_min=2, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=58, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.strftime(datefmt, paris_time[0]), time.strftime(datefmt, paris_time[1])
('2013-02-27 11:02:02 CET', '2013-02-27 12:02:02 CET')
>>>
```

Then I changed my machine timezone to "New York" and replayed the last commands:

```
>>> paris_time[0]
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=11, tm_min=2, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=58, tm_isdst=0)
>>> paris_time[1]
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=12, tm_min=2, tm_sec=2, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=58, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.strftime(datefmt, paris_time[0]), time.strftime(datefmt, paris_time[1])
('2013-02-27 11:02:02 EST', '2013-02-27 12:02:02 EST')
>>>
```

For information: CET is the code for +0100 and EST is the code for -0500.

The python [time.strftime(format[, t])](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/time.html#time.strftime) documentation states in the table that:

> %Z    Time zone name (no characters if no time zone exists).

What does "no time zone exists" means? time zone in the **struct_time object** (edit: I initially wrote 'strftime object' in my question) or in the system ? According to my tests, I have no timezone set in the objects paris_time[x] but there is a timezone displayed.
So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

the python date routines are (1) a confusing mess and (2) a thin wrapper around system calls.

on my (linux) machine, `man strftime` shows information about the system call `strftime` that the python routine presumably wraps.  and there it says that the system TZ is used.  this can be modified with [tzset](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/time.html#time.tzset).

as far as "no time zone exists" - i imagine it means when the system TZ is unset.

(and i have no idea how this carries across to windows.)